# React Native insert variable

Tags: react-native

Trying to figure out the syntax for inserting a variable in a function.

```
var SlidesArray = ['Slide0', 'Slide1'];
var Slides = SlidesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * SlidesArray.length)];

<Text>{Slides}</Text>
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('{Slides}'); }}>
  <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 18 }}>Get New Activity {Slides}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

When this renders, I see the value of `{Slides}` on the screen.

How to do I get that to work inside of

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('{Slides}'); }}>
```

The goal here is to navigate to a random View from an array of Views.

`onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate({Slides}); }}` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove brackets and single quotes on both sides of `Slides`.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate(Slides);
```